# Autoresize Masking Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, autoresizingmask

I have a ViewController which calls another view which contains a `contentView` and then a `webView` on top. I am trying to add buttons on top of `webView` and been trying to get them to work with auto resize masking for about two hours now with no success. When I tried to reset the frame upon rotation, the buttons takes a few minutes to reposition so it looks laggy. Here's my `init` method for the view:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        _contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;

        UIImage *facebookShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"share_facebook_focus_pad"];
        self.facebookButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(700, 150, facebookShare.size.width, facebookShare.size.height)];
        //[facebookButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
        [self.facebookButton setImage:facebookShare forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_webView addSubview:self.facebookButton];

        UIImage *twitterShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"share_twitter_focus_pad"];
        self.twitterButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.facebookButton.frame.origin.x, self.facebookButton.frame.origin.y + facebookShare.size.height, twitterShare.size.width, twitterShare.size.height)];
        //twitterButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.twitterButton setImage:twitterShare forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_webView addSubview:self.twitterButton];

        UIImage *mailShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"share_mail_focus_pad"];
        self.mailButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.facebookButton.frame.origin.x, self.facebookButton.frame.origin.y + facebookShare.size.height + twitterShare.size.height, mailShare.size.width, mailShare.size.height)];
        //mailButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.mailButton setImage:mailShare forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_webView addSubview:self.mailButton];

        [_contentView addSubview:_webView];
        [self addSubview:_contentView];

        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));

    }
```

Simply just adding three buttons on top of `_webView`. I am trying to have them at the top right corner and therefore, I need to mask `left` and `bottom`. In here I commented out twitter and mail buttons and just testing it out with Facebook button. I **specifically** set the the Facebook button to be at x-coordinate 700 - yet as soon as I uncomment the autoresize mask line as shown above, the Facebook button disappears!! How does this happen? Autoresize mask does not play around with the x-coordinate unless it has been rotated! And even though, it should nicely align it according and push it to the top-right as I masked left and bottom. What is going here? This is extremely frustrating - I've been battling with it for about 2 hours!

**P.S: I am not using Interface Builder. And please do not suggest that I use it.**

Comment: does your super view has autoresizesSubviews set to YES?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
self.facebookButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

and set the frame of the webview first and then add the buttons and then try changing the orientation.